# ASP.NET Core RC2 Configure Custom AppSettings

Tags: asp.net, configuration, asp.net-core

Say I put the settings below in appsettings.json.

```
"MySettings": {
    "SmtpHost": "smtp.mydomain.com"",
    "WebService": "http://localhost:1337"
}
```

And I have the class below to hold those settings.

```
public class MySettings
{
    public string SmtpHost{ get; set; }
    public string WebService{ get; set; }
}
```

With RC1 I would use the line of code below in the ConfigureServices() method to load those configuration settings.

```
services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
```

But in RC2 that same line of code gives me this error

> Cannot convert from
>   'MicrosoftExtensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection' to
>   'System.Action`<MySettings>`'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You simply need to reference a different package with **RC2**. In your `project.json` simply add a reference to the `"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final"` package, and you'll get the correct extension method that you're looking for.

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
}
```

Like several of the changes with **ASP.NET Core RC2**, there was a lot of re-packing and moving of things. I put together a [migration guide](https://ievangelist.github.io/blog/migrating-to-rc2/) that you might find useful.

Comment: LOL.  I posted the question with the intent of answering it myself because I couldn't find an answer to it on SO.  So other people who might run into the same problem can get a quick answer.  You beat me to it.  Nice job!

Comment: @ClintB, I pointed this out to the community on the .NET slack room. There was a lot of initial confusion about it. I'm happy I could help.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I bookmarked it and will read over it.  I was trying to decide who to give the accepted answer to between you and Joe. Your migration guide makes you the winner.

Comment: @ClintB, thanks. BTW - he is in the same slack room, so he probably got the answer from me originally :P

Answer (score 3):

you need to add the package:

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
```

and make sure you have this using:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
```

Comment: LOL.  I posted the question with the intent of answering it myself because I couldn't find an answer to it on SO.  So other people who might run into the same problem can get a quick answer.  You beat me to it.  Nice job!